# Problema ao deixar link ativo - Rotas Angular 2

Tags: angular

Estou com problemas ao adicionar a classe no meu link da página ativa.
Funciona em todas as páginas, porém o da index fica sempre ativo. Por exemplo: se eu estiver na página de aplicação fica ativo os dois links.

**Menu:**

```
<li><a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="ativo">Página inicial</a></li>
<li><a routerLink="/aplicacao" routerLinkActive="ativo">Aplicações</a></li>
```

**Route:**

```
{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },
{ path: 'aplicacao', component: AplicacaoComponent },
```

Alguém já teve problema parecido?

Comment: Tente aplicaro seu routerLink com os colchetes de atributo: <a [routerLink]="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="class1 class2">Bob</a>. Todos os exemplos na documentação estão usando: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

Comment: Não funciona. Já havia testado. :/

Comment: Você definiu uma <base href="/"> no seu head?  Olhando no Tour of Heroes percebi que eles mudaram algumas coisas do RC5 para o lançamento, tente ajustar seu router de acordo com o exemplo deles: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#base-href

Comment: lfarroco, defini sim. Estou fuçando aqui enquanto isso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por padrão, o Angular 2 coloca como active, qualquer url que **ao menos** tenha a url configurada no routerLinkActive. Ou seja, a URL "/" existe no "/aplicacao". Assim sendo, o Angular 2 coloca active tanto no primeiro elemento, quanto no segundo.

**Para resolver este problema:**

Nos docs da diretiva routerLinkActive existe uma outra diretiva onde você passa as opções do mesmo, essa diretiva se chama [routerLinkActiveOptions], na qual você pode passar como valor, um objeto com o parâmetro 'exact' (booleano). Configurando este parâmetro como true, fará com que o routerLinkActive só adicione a classe que você passou no "routerLinkActive" nos links exatos. Assim sendo, caso sua URL seja exatamente "/", ou exatamente "/aplicacao", será adicionada o active respectivamente.

**Exemplo na prática**

```
<li><a routerLink="/" routerLinkActive="ativo" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">Página inicial</a></li>
<li><a routerLink="/aplicacao" routerLinkActive="ativo">Aplicações</a></li>
```

É da sua escolha usar a diretiva "[routerLinkActiveOptions]" no "/aplicacao". Você faria isso se você deseja criar outro sublink, por exemplo: Com a URL "/aplicacao/app1".

**Porquê o Angular 2 faz isso como padrão?**

Por exemplo, essa funcionalidade é muito útil quando você deseja criar um "Nested menu" (Menu dropdown com múltiplos níveis), com esse recurso você consegue aplicar o CSS em todos os actives de forma prática, em todos os níveis de menus ativados.

**Docs:**

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

Answer (score 0):

Fala Brother!

cara, passei exatamente por este problema quando comecei a programar com Angular.
Pode se dizer que quando você coloca o Path "/", em qualquer rota que seja adicionada ele ainda vai reconhecer a "/", por isso ele deixa ela Ativa.
Cheguei na solução da seguinte forma:

Vamos supor que sua página inicial seja a HOME. No seu App-routing-module.ts faça desta forma:

```
{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent},
{ path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full'}
```

e no seu Menu, direcione para "/home" ao invés de "/":

```
<a class="nav-link" routerLink="/home">
```

Desta forma, qualquer outro trecho de seu código você pode definir o routerLink para "/" que automaticamente vai redirecionar para "/home", assim não afeta os demais links de seu Menu. O unico detalhe é que sempre vai estar com o /home, "www.site.com/home" e não "www.site.com", tem gente que tem toc com isso, mas é uma solução bem efetiva para o problema do Menu.